# MySQL 'or' statement with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

when building the query in mySQL, How do I fetch the result with multiple values

Example code:

```
if (strtolower($_REQUEST['shirt_color']) == 'showall' && (isset($_REQUEST['shirt_type']))
        {
            $params[] = array('field' => 'color_type',
                       'operator' => '=',
                      'value' => 'black'
                              );
        }
```

The above pice of code works fine and gets the correct results, However I want to search for two different colors:

I tried putting --- `'value' => "'black' OR 'white'"`
but it doesnt work.

Comment: You should show us how these params are processed by script generating sql query. One thing that comes to my mind is setting an operator to `IN` and value to `('black', 'white')`

Comment: Please display the raw query sent to the database

Comment: show us your query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `IN` operator. Something like that shall be your resulting query:

```
SELECT * FROM tshirts WHERE color IN ('black','white');
```

If you provide us with the code you have to generate the query string, we could help you with adapting it to the `IN` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like

```
Select * from tshirts where color = 'black' OR color = 'white'
```

Comment: Should there be only unique key for dictionary, I believe?